# How to rewrite this IIFE into an ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

So I have this IIFE, and for the sake of consistence with other ES6 classes I rewrote for a plugin, I also want to rewrite this into using ES6 Class syntax. Can anyone show me how to do it?

```
Foo = (function(){
    Foo.bar = function(a, b){
        baz = new this(a, b);

        return baz;
    }

    function Foo(a, b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    return Foo;

})();
```

Comment: It's very confusing using `Foo` as both the global name of the class and a local function inside the class.

Comment: The IIFE simply returns a function with a single public member. No advantage is taken of the IIFE, it can be converted to a plain function declaration and property assignment without any issues. There are no classes in javascript (ECMAScript). There are functions that can be constructors.

Comment: There's a `class` declaration, which is ES6 syntax for defining all the related functions and objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: [*"Even though ECMAScript includes syntax for class definitions, ECMAScript objects are not fundamentally class-based…"*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-objects), but yes, there is a [*ClassDeclaration*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-ClassDeclaration).

Comment: Why was IIFE concerned before ES6 ? to imitate classes ?!

Comment: @Barmar using a local scoped declaration inside the IIFE is a quite standard practice (with performance and encapsulation advantages), as long as both variables have the same value it shouldn't be too confusing either. What *is* confusing is the usage of `Foo` above its declaration; while totally valid it should be avoided when not necessary.

Comment: @ProllyGeek—IIFEs exploit closures and can be used for many purposes, including emulating features of classes.

Answer (score 4):

It would be a simple

```
class Foo {
    constructor(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    static bar(a, b) {
        return new this(a, b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function created by the IIFE can be just as well created using a plain function declaration and property assignment:

```js
function Foo(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}

Foo.bar = function(a, b) {
  baz = new this(a, b);
  return baz;
}

var foo = new Foo('FooA', 'FooB');
console.log(foo.a + ':' + foo.b);

var baz = Foo.bar('BazA', 'BazB');
console.log(baz.a + ':' + baz.b);
```

Using the [*class* syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  static bar(a, b){
    baz = new this(a, b);
    return baz;
  }
}

var foo = new Foo('FooA','FooB');
console.log(foo.a + ':' + foo.b);

var baz = Foo.bar('BazA', 'BazB');
console.log(baz.a + ':' + baz.b);
```

Unfortunately I can't actually run this code as the site I'm currently on has SOE versions of Firefox and IE that don't recognise the *class* syntax. So please update if it's faulty.